# Add or override properties of already defined function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function with the following structure:

```
function someFunctions() {
  this.DOSOMETHING = function(parameters){
    //some logic
  }
}
```

This is loaded in another file and instantiated as an object that is then being used:

```
load('file_containing_someFunctions.js')
var someFunctions = new someFunctions();

function doTheThing(parameters) { 
  //some logic
  someFunctions.DOSOMETHING(parameters)
}
```

I would like to load another file after the first one which overrides or adds properties to someFunctions() before the object is instantiated.

```
load('file_containing_someFunctions.js')
load('file_containing_extended_functions.js')
var someFunctions = new someFunctions();

function doTheThing(parameters) { 
  //some logic
  someFunctions.DOSOMETHINGELSE(parameters)
}
```

How should I define **DOSOMETHINGELSE** in **file_containing_extended_functions.js**? Is it possible? It's worth noting that the code is rather old and used in old browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `new` keyword, you are instantiating a new object whose constructor function is `someFunctions`. The constructor creates a function called `DOSOMETHING` and assigns it as a property of the newly created object. This goes against the OOP paradigm in JavaScript where object methods should be members of the object's prototype, not the object itself.

You may transform the constructor code as follows:

```
function someFunctions() { }
someFunctions.prototype.DOSOMETHING = function(parameters) {}
```

In your extension script you may then add and override methods by modifying the `someFunctions.prototype` object.

If you insist on keeping the current implementation of `someFunctions`, you may create a new function with the same name, internally calling the old `someFunctions` constructor and modifying the returned object:

```
const oldSomeFunctions = someFunctions;

var someFunctions = function() {
    const base = new oldSomeFunctions();
    base.DOSOMETHING = console.log;
    base.DOSOMETHINGELSE = console.info;
    
    return base;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood you correctly, both of those would work after instantiating the someFunctions object, right? In this case I'd need to do it before instantiation.

Comment: @Fermar No, this code must be run before instantiation. It modifies the `someFunctions` class so that objects instantiated with `new someFunctions()` are given new/overridden methods.

Comment: I followed your first advice, thank you!